# How to combine objects that have arrays?

Tags: javascript

How can I combine two objects recursively following these rules:

- nested objects are combined in exactly the same way
- arrays common to the two objects should be represented in the output as the entire second object's array concatenated onto the end of the entire first object's array
- if the second object has a key that the first object also has (and it is not an array or an object value), then just overwrite the first object's with the second object's

```js
let obj1 = {
  'foo': [
    'one',
    'two',
    'three'
  ],
  'bar': 'hello'
};

let obj2 = {
  'foo': ['five'],
  'world': 'earth'
};
```

`Object.assign(obj1, obj2)` returns `{ foo: [ 'five' ], bar: 'hello', world: 'earth' }`, it has overwritten the entire `foo` array instead of just added `obj2`'s items to it.

I want

```js
combine(obj1, obj2) ->
{
  'foo': [
    'one',
    'two',
    'three',
    'five'
  ],
  'bar': 'hello',
  'world': 'earth'
}
```

---

Is there nothing less verbose than my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all the keys of the second object:

- if the key exists on the first object, merge the values according to

  - if they are both arrays, concatenation
  - if they are both objects, the original method (recursive)
  - otherwise, just the second value
- if the key does not exist on the first object, add the second object's key/value pair

```js
function mergeObjects(...objects) {
    return objects.reduce((accum, current) => {
        Object.keys(current).forEach(key => {
            if (accum.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                accum[key] = merge(accum[key], current[key]);
            } else {
                accum[key] = current[key];
            }
        });
        return accum;
    }, {});
}

function merge(left, right) {
    if (Array.isArray(right)) {
        if (Array.isArray(left)) {
            return left.concat(right);
        } else {
            return right;
        }
    } else if (isPlainObject(right)) {
        if (isPlainObject(left)) {
            return mergeObjects(left, right);
        } else {
            return right;
        }
    } else {
        return right;
    }
}

function isPlainObject(o) {
    return o !== undefined && o.constructor !== undefined && o.constructor.prototype === Object.prototype;
}
```

`mergeObjects(obj1, obj2)` does what you want